# Windows 10/11 VPN, Split Tunneling and App-based redirect

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, ip

As explained in the title I need to enable split tunnel on a Windows 10/11 VPN and redirect only some specific applications. I googled a lot, I tried several solutions but without success. First of all I created a VPN then I enabled the split tunneling with the following command in the Powershell:

```
Set-VPNconnection -name [VPN_CONNECTION_NAME] -SplitTunneling $true
```

After this, I obtain that everything is routed to the standard ISP instead of the VPN gateway.

Now I need to redirect some applications to the VPN. I tried several approach based on some articles I found on google. For example I enable a autotrigger application switch with the following command:

```
Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication-Name [VPN_CONNECTION_NAME] –ApplicationID [PATH_TO_MY_APPLICATION]
```

With this command, I obtain that when I run my selected application, the associated VPN establishes the connection. This confirms that the trigger works properly. But the connection of my selected applications are not redirected to the VPN, but still use the default ISP gateway, even if the articles I found claim that when the application is added in the autotrigger pool they should be redirected.

Until now the best solution I found is to add a static route to the IP which my application connect to. I used this command from the VPN

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName [VPN_CONNECTION_NAME] -DestinationPrefix 192.168.11.0/24
```

I have 2 problems with this approach:

1. I have to found all the IP address the application connect to, and they are a lot of IP.
2. Worst I have 2 application that for one of them connections, have the same destination address, this is a problem since I want that just the application A pass to the VPN, and not the application B, even if the destination address is the same.

I know there are several commercial VPN that have this option of App-Based split tunneling, but I cannot use them. Any solution?

Comment: I am working on an application that solves this issue. It is currently in the early stages of development and based on the WireGuard protocol. I'm in need of testers. I put a site up https://tunnl.to if you're interested in trying it out please get in contact!

Comment: Thank you, but I really need something really stable for what I have to do. When it will be stable I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I also went down this path and found the deceptive articles that claim Windows can do split tunneling using the powershell commands `Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication-Name`

The only thing that does is automatically connects the VPN when those applications are started, leaving you to manage all the IP addresses that those applications use which are dynamic and are near impossible to keep track of.

Application based split tunneling is not a feature built into Windows.

As I mentioned in the comments, I am developing a WireGuard vpn client built around split tunneling. The project is on GitHub https://github.com/TunnlTo/desktop-app

Comment: Thank you, I want to specify my networks skills aren't so advanced, so maybe I could say something stupid: I saw it is base on WireGuard VPN, so if my server uses IPSec I suppose I cannot use your tool, am I right?

Comment: You're correct, TunnlTo does not have IPSec support at the moment.